# tripleDES encryption in Swift 3

Tags: swift, 3des, tripledes

Can anyone please help me with tutorials or sample code for TripleDES decryption in Swift. I receiving a web service response data as 3DES encrypted and I need to decrypt via my app and show the data in app

I am using this code snippet, but it doesn't work for me:

```
func myDecrypt(decryptData : NSData) -> NSData?{\
    let mydata_len : Int = decryptData.length
    let keyData : NSData = (helperObject.decryptionKey as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as NSData

    let buffer_size : size_t = mydata_len+kCCBlockSizeAES128
    let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<NSData>.allocate(capacity: buffer_size)
    var num_bytes_encrypted : size_t = 0

    var _ : [UInt8] = [56, 101, 63, 23, 96, 182, 209, 205]  // I didn't use

    let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCDecrypt)
    let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
    let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)
    let keyLength        = size_t(kCCKeySize3DES)

    let decrypt_status : CCCryptorStatus = CCCrypt(operation, algoritm, options, keyData.bytes, keyLength, nil, decryptData.bytes, mydata_len, buffer, buffer_size, &num_bytes_encrypted)

    if UInt32(decrypt_status) == UInt32(kCCSuccess){\
        let myResult : NSData = NSData(bytes: buffer, length: num_bytes_encrypted)
        free(buffer)
        print("decrypt \(myResult)")

        let stringResult = NSString(data: myResult as Data, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print(stringResult ?? "No string decription")
        return myResult
    }else{
        free(buffer)
        return nil\
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Users on this site love to help you if you can share an attempt you made to solve the issue. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to increase the likelihood of getting your questions answered.

Comment: 1. 3DES should not be used in new work, it is not particularly secure. 2 You want to decrypt something encrypted with 3DES and yet in the code there is `kCCBlockSizeAES128`, that is incorrect for DES. 3. What is the actual key size supplied? 4. ECB mode is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.